# How does the boost tuple 'get' method work?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tuples

After delving into the source of the excellent boost tuple class (tuple_basic.hpp), I can see that a recursive templated algorithm is used in the 'get' method for accessing the tuple members.

What I'm struggling to understand is how a numeric templated parameter can be mapped into a specific member name?, additionally, won't the recursive template function always converge to the first element (as in, the stop condition of the recursive template function, get<0>())?, how are elements greater than zero accessed?

Answer (score 2):

As a baby example, you can imagine something like this - just a tuple of one fixed type for now:

```
template <int N> struct MyTuple : MyTuple<N - 1>
{
    T data;
};
template <> struct MyTuple<0> { };
```

The real-world solution would of course have variadic template parameters for the data types, and would also provide a variadic constructor, constructing `data` with the first element and passing the remaining elements to the base constructor.

Now we can try and access the `i`th element:

```
template <int K> struct get_impl
{
    template <int N> static T & get(MyTuple<N> & t)
    {
        return get_impl<K - 1>::get(static_cast<MyTuple<N - 1>&>(t));
    }
};
template <> struct get_impl<0>
{
    template <int N> static T & get(MyTuple<N> & t)
    {
        return t.data;
    }
};
```

The key here is to have a specialization when `K = 0` which extracts the actual element, and to cast up the inheritance hierarchy until you're there. Finally, we slingshot the tuple type deduction through a function template:

```
template <int K, int N> T & get(MyTuple<N> & t)
{
    return get_impl<K>::get(t);
}
```

Comment: This I understand, what I don't get is how tuples consisting of multiple values are handled using the recursive template method?

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: You just add variadic template parameters to the tuple definition. You can use `auto`/`decltype` for the return value of `get` to make things simpler.

Comment: Aren't variadic templates C++x11?, the boost tuple implementation is not dependent on this feature

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: You can "fake" variadic templates up to a finite limit with lots of ugly preprocessor macros. I think that's what Boost does. But conceptually think "variadic".